# Declare iVar using blocks in objective c

Tags: iphone

I am new to blocks. I want to create a iVar NSMutableArray which I can access inside a block method.Can someone please tell me how to declare it using _block keyword?`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    __block NSMutableArray *array;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Comment: @InderKumarRathore It was 25% when I wrote it.

Comment: @Anicho please look at his activity before remarking. It most likely he saw the comment and fixed the rate before you noticed.

Comment: @giorashc It was 71 when I looked. Anyways put %age in your comment next time hope that will clear everyone next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generally not be accessing ivars from within anything but `init` and `dealloc`. So there's almost never a reason to access an ivar directly from within a block. Instead, use accessors on the object that owns the ivar (often `self`).

For multi-threaded blocks this will look something like this:

```
__weak id weakself = self;
[obj doSomethingWithBlock:^{
   id strongself = weakself;
   strongself.array = nil; // Can't safely read from the array here without more code.
}];
```

If this is not a multi-threaded operation, then you can just do this:

```
__weak id weakself = self;
[obj doSomethingWithBlock:^{
   NSLog(@"%@", weakself.array[0]);
}];
```

If there is no danger of a retain loop (because the block executes immediately on this thread), you can do this even more simply:

```
[obj doSomethingWithBlock:^{
   NSLog(@"%@", self.array[0]);
}];
```

Comment: Any reference from Apple Documentation for this ?

Comment: Which part? General guidance on properties is given here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html Regarding use of weak references to avoid loops, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set the `__block` in front of your iVar.

According to : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

> When a block is copied, it creates strong references to object
>   variables used within the block. If you use a block within the
>   implementation of a method:
>
> - If you access an instance variable by reference, a strong reference is made to self;
> - If you access an instance variable by value, a strong reference is made to the variable.